# No automapping and schema creation with Fluent NHibernate: I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I can't figure out why Fluent NHibernate automapping and schema generation aren't working.

I've this code:

```
    return Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database
    (
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString
        (
            c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("dataAccess")
        )
    )
    .Mappings(config => config.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assembly(ObjectsAssembly, new ORMAutoMappingConfiguration())))
    .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory()
    .OpenSession();
```

And:

```
public sealed class ORMAutoMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        return member.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DomainObject));
    }
}
```

The database and mappings aren't created.

"ObjectsAssembly" is a one got in a property, I've watched it and I could determine that this is the right assembly and it has domain objects inheriting DomainObject.

Another thing is automapping configuration class is never required in the process, ShouldMap isn't invoked by FNH.

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, database connection works, a connection is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this was a very easy to solve problem! I was overriding ShouldMap(Member) instead of ShouldMap(Type) overload.

That's any type was going to be mapped, which is wrong because not all of them were domain objects.

I've my domain model and database working!

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say whats wrong with your automappings but to use Schema generation you need

```
var schema = new SchemaExport(configuration);
schema.Create(true, true);
```

Comment: I got it working, there was a very stupid problem... See my automapping configuration implementation: it implements ShouldMap(Member) overload instead of ShouldMap(Type) one. What was wrong? Any type was going to be mapped and FNH failed to that because not all types in that assembly are domain objects. Thank you anyway!!